# Nombre de columna a primer campo de un csv

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un código que me permite exportar información desde una tabla en mi base de datos pero me gustaría que cada vez que exporte al archivo coloque el nombre de la columna.

```
<?
    if($_POST[exportar] == "expbas"){

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM pruebas WHERE (fecha BETWEEN '".$_POST[fecha_inicial]."' AND '".$_POST[fecha_final]."')";
        $result = $usuario->consulta($consulta);
        $arr_datos = $usuario->ciclo_de_filas($result);

        $file = fopen("tmp/base_".str_replace("-","",$_POST[fecha_inicial])."_".str_replace("-","",$_POST[fecha_final]).".csv", "w");

        for($xx = 0; $xx < count($arr_datos); $xx++){
            fwrite($file, $arr_datos[$xx][expediente].";".$arr_datos[$xx][fecha]. PHP_EOL);
        }

        fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El nombre de las columnas no es más que una primera fila en un archivo CSV, antes del ciclo que va escribiendo los valores, agrega una línea con el título de las columnas, así:

```
fwrite($file "expediente;fecha".PHP_EOL);
```

Ya con eso la primera fila contendrá los *títulos* de tus columnas.

[Edición]
He añadido la concatenación al final del caracter de fin de línea, luego que @jaime me hiciera ver en comentarios el olvido.

Comment: Me funciono despues de un pequeño cambio fwrite($file "expediente;fecha". PHP_EOL );

Comment: Oh, si, lo siento, olvidé el fin de línea, voy a incorporar la mejora en la respuesta ahora mismo. Gracias por el dato.